# An alternative to ngrok that doesn't have any time constraints

Tags: laravel, ngrok

Since ngrok has a time limit of like 5/7 hours I don't know. I want to be able to let someone demo a software without like deploying it online since it's not yet a service.

Answer (score 8):

The [ngrok.io/upgrade](https://ngrok.io/upgrade) says:

There are limits for users who don't have a ngrok account: tunnels can only stay open for a fixed period of time and consume a limited amount of bandwidth.

So all you need to do is sign up for a free account and your tunnels will only expire if reset your computer/server or if you restart ngrok.

However, if your goal is to have a vanity URL and not pay for ngrok, you can use a subdomain of an existing website to point to the ngrok tunnel. But a) keep in mind the URL of the ngrok tunnel will change each time you restart ngrok on the host which would mean you'd have to update your DNS entries; and b) you may not be able to enable https for obvious reasons.

Comment: Wow I dno't know that :) Thanks a lot @Azeame

Comment: Do I have to pay anything for this ??

Comment: I get this comment from one of the guys who talked to me
`ngrok is an external package and you have to pay for the service if you don't want it to expire as mentioned before
https://ngrok.com/
`

Comment: Well I use it everyday and have only signed up for the free account and there are two things I can tell you from my personal experience, your tunnels only expire when you restart ngrok and you cannot have vanity URLs on the free account, it will randomly assign a URL each time you start ngrok. Perhaps they are referring to static or vantiy URLs. You can confirm on the pricing page that they limit the number of concurrent connections per minute (40/minute) there are no limitations for how long they are open [https://ngrok.com/pricing](https://ngrok.com/pricing)

Comment: One of my machines on the free tier has had its tunnel open for over 6 months now which exposes a limited API and I haven't needed to restart ngrok. I can't imagine I was grandfathered in to some features that aren't available anymore.